# TypeError with redux - thunk : middleware is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am using applyMiddleware from redux which takes middleware as a parameter and I have passed thunk but somehow I am not able to resolve this issue related to middleware is not a function.

Below is the piece of my code. In this code I am trying to pass the redux thunk to applyMiddleware

```
import Redux from 'redux'
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    users: [],
    error: '',   
}


const FETCH_USERS_REQUESTED = 'FETCH_USERS_REQUESTED'
const FETCH_USERS_SUCCEEDED = 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCEEDED'
const FETCH_USERS_FAILED = 'FETCH_USERS_FAILED'
```

Here are my action creators.

```
const fetchUsersRequest = () =>{
    return{
        type: FETCH_USERS_REQUESTED,
    }
}

const fetchUsersSuccess = (users) =>{
    return{
        type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCEEDED,
        payload: users,
    }
}

const fetchUserFailure = (error) =>{
    return{
        type: FETCH_USERS_FAILED,
        payload: error,
    }
}
```

Here is my reducer

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case FETCH_USERS_REQUESTED:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }
        case FETCH_USERS_SUCCEEDED:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                users: action.payload,
                error: ''
            }
        case FETCH_USERS_FAILED:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                users: [],
                error: action.payload,
            }
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to create the store

```
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

The error I am getting is below

```
        return middleware(middlewareAPI);
               ^

TypeError: middleware is not a function
    at D:\CDAC_2022\WPT\HarryReact\Codvelution-Redux\REDUX-DEMO\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:703:16
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at D:\CDAC_2022\WPT\HarryReact\Codvelution-Redux\REDUX-DEMO\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:702:31
    at createStore (D:\CDAC_2022\WPT\HarryReact\Codvelution-Redux\REDUX-DEMO\node_modules\redux\lib\redux.js:162:33)
    at file:///D:/CDAC_2022/WPT/HarryReact/Codvelution-Redux/REDUX-DEMO/asyncActions.js:62:15
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)

Node.js v20.9.0
```

Comment: Are you certain you have all the project dependencies correctly installed? Also, just FYI, if you are using Redux-Toolkit you should be using its `configureStore` function to create the store object, which includes the Thunk middleware by default (*e.g. no extra setup required and the `redux-thunk` dependency should be removed*). Also, Node 20 *might* be too new for your tooling, if this is at all part of the issue. Try an older version like Node 16.

Comment: Generally, the tutorial you are following is severely outdated, as Redux has changed a lot in the last 4 years. Not a single line of code would even look remotely like that in modern Redux. Please follow the official Redux tutorial instead: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts